# Add path to python package to sys.path

Tags: python

I have a case for needing to add a path to a python package to `sys.path` (instead of its parent directory), but then refer to the package normally by name. 
Maybe that's weird, but let me exemplify what I need and maybe you guys know how to achieve that.

I have all kind of experimental folders, modules, etc inside a path like /home/me/python.
Now I don't want to add that folder to my `sys.path` (`PYTHONPATH`) since there are experimental modules which names could clash with something useful. 
But, inside `/home/me/python` I want to have a folder like `pyutils`. So I want to add `/home/me/python/pyutils` to `PYTHONPATH`, but, be able to refer to the package by its name `pyutils`...like I would have added `/home/me/python` to the path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll answer to my own question since I got an idea while writing the question, and maybe someone will need that.
I added a link from that folder to my site-packages folder like that:
`ln -s /home/me/python/pyutils /path/to/site-packages/pyutils`

Then, since the PYTHONPATH contains the `/path/to/site-packages` folder, and I have a `pyutils` folder in it, with **init**.py, I can just import like:

`from pyutils import mymodule`

And the rest of the `/home/me/python` is not in the `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 2):

One helpful fact is that adding something to the python path is different from importing it into your interpreter. You can structure your modules and submodules such that names will not clash.

[Look here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) regarding how to create modules. I read the documents, but I think that module layout takes a little learning-by-doing, which means creating your modules, and then importing them into scripts, and see if the importing is awkward or requires too much qualification.

Separately consider the [python import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). When you import something you can use the "import ... as" feature to name it something different as you import, and thereby prevent naming clashes.

You seem to have already understood how you can change the PYTHONPATH using sys.path(), as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108285/in-python-script-how-do-i-set-pythonpath).

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options:

- Make a new directory `pyutilsdir`, place `pyutils` in `pyutilsdir`,
  and then add `pyutilsdir` to PYTHONPATH.
- Move the experimental code outside of `/home/me/python` and add `python` to
  your `PYTHONPATH`.
- Rename the experimental modules so their names do not clash with
  other modules. Then add `python` to `PYTHONPATH`.
- Use a version control system like `git` or `hg` to make the
  experimental modules available or unavailable as desired.

  You could have a `master` branch without the experimental modules,
  and a `feature` branch that includes them. With git, for example, you could switch between
  the two with

  ```
  git checkout [master|feature]
  ```

  The contents of `/home/me/python/pyutils` (the git repo directory) would
  change depending on which commit is checked out. Thus, using version control, you can keep the experimental modules in `pyutils`, but only make them present when you checkout the `feature` branch.