# How do i ensure i can import pythoncom and pywintypes so i can build a COM server in python 3.4?

Tags: python, com-server

Im a trying to build a COM server in Python. I have downloaded and installed Pywin32 (I use 32-bit version of Python 3.4.1, so I downloaded and installed pywin32 for this version).

Now, in order to import pythoncom in IDLE, I need to have two .dll files readily accessible:
-pythoncom.dll
-pywintypes.dll

Both .dll files are in the following directory:

C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32

When I give the import statement in IDLE, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in 
    import pywintypes
ImportError: No module named 'pywintypes'

I reinstalled pywin32, but it still doesn't fix it.

I am now trying to add C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32 to my PATH directory, but it doesn’t work. I am trying this via:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32
```

I then get the following message:

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

What error am I making in the syntax above? How can I fix this (i.e. how can I add C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py to my PATH environment)?

Comment: Even if you do fix the syntax, I don't think it's going to work, because of the reasons explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108285/in-python-script-how-do-i-set-pythonpath).