# How to have multi-directory or multi-package python project?

Tags: python, package

I have project structure like this:

```
package1/__init__.py
package1/file1.py
package1/file2.py

package2/__init__.py
package2/file1.py
package2/file2.py

__init__.py
script1.py
script2.py
```

Unfortunately, I found that I can run code only from root directory, for example, from `script1.py`. If I run say from `pakage2/file2.py`, all links between files are lost, i.e. all imports of `package1` from `package2` becomes not found.

What is the correct directory structure in Python, which constraints package structure over all directories?

Answer (score 0):

You either need both `package1` and `package2` to be inside a package, in which case they can both import from each other:

```
root_package/
    __init__.py
    package1/
    package2/
```

Or add the packages to your `PYTHONPATH`, in which case any python script on your system can import from them:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/package1:/path/to/package2"
```

**Update:** you cannot import as part of a package if you are running the scripts directly. What you should do is define classes and functions in your packages as desired, then import them from another script:

```
root_package/
    __init__.py
    my_script.py
    package1/
    package2/
```

`script.py`:

```
from package1 import ...
from package2 import ...
```

Comment: Sorry, of course I have `__init__.py` file in root directory too, I fixed the question

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't help

Comment: By "another script" you mean "script in root directory but not in any subdirectories"?

Comment: yes, or a script elsewhere that has `root_package` in it's `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: I don't want to. Directories were invented to group files in logical groups. I want to keep this invention intact. I don't want to have long plain list of dozens of scripts of different purposes laying in one directory as was in PCM operating system

Comment: then you can add the root package to your `PYTHONPATH` and put the script anywhere. Or, dynamically add it to `PYTHONPATH` inside your script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108285/in-python-script-how-do-i-set-pythonpath

Comment: either way, a `.py` file can be part of a package or run as a standalone script, but not both.