# Inner nested class access from robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Robot - 3.1.1
Python - 3.7.3

I wanted to access method that are written in nested inner class from robot framework.

**Robot:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library             ../***/***/***/OrderList.py

    *** Keywords ***

    Click from order
        click_order
```

**Python:**

```
class OrderList():
           pass
class Ordertable(OrderList):
       def click_order(self):
            foo
```

I am getting below error while running the above robot suite.

```
No keyword with name 'click_order' found.
```

If I move the click_order method under parent class (OrderList) like below, then robot could recognize.

```
class OrderList():
    def click_order(self):
            foo
class Ordertable(OrderList):
       pass
```

Could someone help me as to what changes required at robot suite to make a call to nested inner class methods?

Comment: Launch your test with this option `--pythonpath ../***/***/***/OrderList.py` and import your library as `OrderList.Ordertable`.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I have added the complete python pah including filename in pythonpath and had imported as per your suggestion but apparently issue still appears. Import error also appears 'failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example about how to import a class as a library and not the whole python file:

1. In a folder named `tests` there is a test.robot and an OrderList.py file.
2. OrderList.py:

   ```
   class OrderList():
              pass

   class Ordertable(OrderList):
          def click_order(self):
               print('foo')
   ```
3. test.robot:

   ```
   *** Settings ***
   Library        OrderList.Ordertable

   *** Test Cases ***
   AA
       click order
   ```
4. Launch it with the following command from the parent folder of the `tests` folder: `robot --pythonpath .\tests\ --test AA .\tests\test.robot`
5. Result:

   ```
   PS prompt> robot --pythonpath .\tests\ --test AA .\tests\test.robot
   ==============================================================================
   Test
   ==============================================================================
   AA                                                                    | PASS |
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Test                                                                  | PASS |
   1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
   1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
   ==============================================================================
   Output:  C:\Users\myuser\output.xml
   Log:     C:\Users\myuser\log.html
   Report:  C:\Users\myuser\report.html
   ```

Comment: This works fine if python and robot comes under same directory but if python file comes from different directory then baseclass.childclass is not accepted. Example: Library  ../Library/OrderList.Ordertable

Comment: If the path passed with `--pythonpath` is an absoluth path then it should work regardless of the working directories.

Comment: Since I am running the robot suite directly from python the '--pythonpath' is not supported. My way of execution is import robot robot.run("C:\\foo\\test_sample.robot", log=log,
          report=report, output=output, loglevel="DEBUG",
          stdout=exec_report)

Comment: You can set pythonpath from python directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108285/in-python-script-how-do-i-set-pythonpath

Answer (score 2):

When Robot Framework imports a library, it tries to import just the class named the same as the .py file - as in your case, the class `OrderList` in the `OrderList.py` file. And it doesn't import any other classes - [check the documentation for more details](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-names).

The easiest option would be to have the class you are going to use renamed, to the same name as the file.

If that's not applicable - and looks like your intent is to use more than one class, you could have the file in your PYTHONPATH (like, physically moving the file to a dir in it, or extend it to include the module's one) and import the classes separately as `OrderList.Ordertable`.
Another would be to solve it on the python side - put each class in a module of their own, each importing the one with the base class.

The first is ops nightmare, the second - design & maintenance; your choice :).

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I tried with specifying nested class like 'Library             ../***/***/***/OrderList.Ordertable' and OrderList.Ordertable.click_order (Keyword call)

Comment: You cannot import the library with `'Library ../***/***/***/OrderList.Ordertable` - it either has to end with `".py"`, when you are importing a python module somewhere in the file system. Or - the .py file itself must be in a directory that's in your PYTHONPATH - then this import will work (and with no "../../" relative paths). Look at the other answer, how to append a dir to the PYTHONPATH temporary - for the run - use the argument `--pythonpath` when you call the `robot` script.