# Importing library failed: in robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have created python file and trying to import that to my robot project.Below is the python file name helloworld.py,

```
class   helloworld:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TESTCASE'
    def fun_scope(self):
        print("Hello World")
```

Below is the robot script,

```
*** Settings ***
Library    helloworld

*** Test Cases ***

TC1
    Fun Scope
```

While executing i am getting below error,

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/Test/custom.robot' on line 2: Importing library 'helloworld' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/venv/bin
  /usr/lib/python38.zip
  /usr/lib/python3.8
  /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
  /home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

I tried all the possible solution but nothing worked :(

Comment: The name of your class should start with a capital letter, though it probably has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifing the name of the library fixes the problem. Just use ***helloworld.py*** in your robot.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    helloworld.py

*** Test Cases ***

TC1
    Fun Scope
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the execution issue but in console still i am getting the Traceback error 
 related to pythonpath which mentioned above

Comment: Using your code i had the same problem, but this was solved with the solution i posted. I get no issues now. Could be a python path problem. have you tried executing your python alone?

Comment: Hi, yes i am not facing any issue while executing python file alone via terminal and IDE

Comment: @SadhaNanda Use the `--pythonpath` argument and specify the files location. Checkout this answer about importing custom libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57672418/3820025.