# problem when Importing keywords robot framework

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I'm importing keywords from a seperate python file but when I use this keywords in the robot file an error appear indicating that this keyword is not declared .

For exemple the routine control is declared in UdsServices and when I use it in a test case it a appear that's not declared

```
*** Settings ***
Library        UdsServices
Variables     ../python_files/Input_variables.py
#Variables      C:/Users/sghribi/eclipse-workspace/robot_UCM-NANO/Ressources/python_files/Input_variables.py


*** Keywords ***
Configure Input Channel
    [Arguments]  @{Framedatas}
    Routine Control  ${CIC_Routine_ID}  ${Framedatas}
```

Routine control function is declared in UdsServices file in a class with the same name as file

```
def routine_control(self, RoutineID, datas=None):

global result
response = None
data = bytes([int(x, 16) for x in datas.split(" ")]) if datas else None
with Client(connexion, request_timeout=3) as client:
    try:
        response = client.routine_control(routine_id=int(RoutineID, 16), control_type=0x01, data=data)
        result = response.data[3:]
    except NegativeResponseException as e:
        print(response.data)
        print('Server refused our request for service %s with code "%s" (0x%02x)' % (
            e.response.service.get_name(), e.response.code_name, e.response.code))
    except InvalidResponseException as e:
        print('Server sent an invalid payload : %s' % e.response.original_payload)
return result
```

I am using eclipse and red and I added the libraries in the red.xml file .

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225091/importing-library-failed-in-robotframework)

Comment: Is the problem only in eclipse, or do you get an error when you run the test? Does the console output and log files show that the library was properly imported?

Comment: In fact when I use a keyword from this libraries eclipse indicates "Unknown keyword"

Comment: Problem resolved . RF V4.0 is not supported by Red so I installed a prior version of rf