# How would I add a directory to windows 10 PATH in from python?

Tags: python, selenium, path

So I'm starting to experiment with Selenium, its really cool and exactly what I needed but it needs the geckodriver added to PATH to work in windows 10. I was wondering if there's a way to automatically do that from my code so when I share it with my friends I don't have walk them through adding it manually

Comment: Instead of put the geckodriver to the path, you can especify where is your executable as `path\to\your\executable`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3108285/11301900 ?