# Python3 package import error even after using __init__.py

Tags: python, import, module, python-3.7

I have the following structure:-

```
Test
├── package1
│   └── script1.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── package2
    └── script2.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I want to import script1.py from script2.py and have tried:-

```
from package1.script1 import *
```

I am running the script python3 script2.py from a linux terminal but this does not seem to work and I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should run a python script from the top level package (which imports and/or runs code that starts the whole application) like the following:

```
Test
├── package1
│   └── script1.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── package2
|   └── script2.py
|   └── __init__.py
|___ run.py
```

Then run `python3 run.py`

When you import `from package1.script1 import *`, you are saying to Python to search the packages from the path the main script was run. Thus it assumes you are searching `package1` from `package2`. If you place `package1` inside `package2` and run `python3 script2.py`, it will also work.

```
Test
├── package2
    ├── package1
    │   └── script1.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── script2.py
    └── __init__.py
```

If you still want to run from script2 with the same directory structure then you have to either be in the `Test` directory and run `python3 package2/script2.py` or modify the [python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108285/in-python-script-how-do-i-set-pythonpath).

Answer (score 0):

Which directory are you in ?

In order to make python to recognize package1,

1 ) You have go to package1's directory via terminal,

```
cd {package1directory}
```

**or**

2 ) You have to append system path to package1's directory as shown below

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/package1dir')
```

3 ) Define PYTHONPATH as system variable. Indicate package1directory